# MASM x86 How to sort an array in ascending order?

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, masm, irvine32

I have managed to successfully sort my array in descending order, but I'm a bit confused about how to sort it into ascending order as well.

I basically want to sort my array into ascending order as well, but I'm kind of stuck. I don't know if I'm overthinking it or not, but I've run into a big roadblock for such a simple problem.

Here's what I have coded for sorting my array of random numbers into descending order:

"""
sortList PROC

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
mov     ecx, [ebp + 8]      
mov     esi, [ebp + 12]     
dec     ecx                 


outer_loop:
    
    
    mov     eax, [esi]
    mov     edx, esi        
    push    ecx

    
    inner_loop:
        
        
        mov     ebx, [esi + 4]          
        mov     eax, [edx]              
        cmp     eax, ebx

        
        jge     do_not_swap

        ;Else, push parameters and swap
        add     esi, 4
        push    esi
        push    edx
        push    ecx
        call    exchange
        sub     esi, 4

        do_not_swap:
        add     esi, 4
        loop    inner_loop

    ;End the inner loop and restore outer loop stuff
    pop     ecx
    mov     esi, edx
    add     esi, 4
    loop    outer_loop


pop     ebp         
ret     8
```

sortList ENDP
"""

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Do you understand this code?  Do you have the C equivalent?  How would you change the sort order in C?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> jge     do_not_swap
> ```

The `jge` instruction means JumpIfGreaterOrEqual.

Reversing the sort order is a simple matter of using `jle` which stands for JumpIfLessOrEqual. That is if the rest of the code works fine like you're saying...

A 1 character change, what great value for your money!